# spatial queries with Linq and Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, linq, entity-framework, sql-server-2008-r2, entity-framework-6

Looking at this basic example taken from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh859721.aspx):

```
var university = (from u in context.Universities 
                        orderby u.Location.Distance(myLocation) 
                        select u).FirstOrDefault();
```

I am wondering where the distance calculation is performed in the situation where the database server is different from the machine hosting the .Net process. Does the above code issue a sql statement that ultimately hits the sql server machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does the above code issue a sql statement that ultimately hits the sql
>   server machine?

Yes.

Comment: Sorry I did not trace this. So you are hundred percent sure about this? Thanks.

Comment: Yes.  It will even use indexes if you have a spatial index on `Location`